# How to return clicked valve in listview of android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

in here after select value from list view i want use that value in another function.plase guild me!!!
 `

```
AnswerListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String Answer = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        Toast.makeText(MCQPaper.this, Answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it to the function within the same class. Something like:

```
public void myFunction(String answer) {

}
```

You can also create an instance variable such as:

```
public String mAnswer;
```

and the use it in the onClickListener:

```
mAnswer = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Answer (score 1):

take String variable global and set in onClick of listview and use these variable into your method like.

```
String Answer ="default value";
    AnswerListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                           Answer = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                            Toast.makeText(MCQPaper.this, Answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
        );
```